# initializing an array by calling a method

Tags: java, initialization

I had this program written in java but I'm facing a difficulty at runtime.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
33. int[][] maze_matrix = input();
    int check = inputCheck(maze_matrix);
    if(check==1){
        startApplication(maze_matrix);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Source and destination entered is not valid.");
    }
}
```

The `input()` method is as follows:

```
 138.private static int[][] input() {


    System.out.println("Enter the size of the maze row_by_column");
    n = in.nextInt(); //Entering rows.
    m = in.nextInt(); //Entering columns.

    int ar_maze[][]= new int[n][m];
    //Initializing the array with given rows and columns.

    for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++) {
152.    ar_maze[i][j] = rand.nextInt(2);
    }

     //Filling array randomly with 0's and 1's.
    return ar_maze;

161.    }
```

I am getting an:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at MazeApplication.input(MazeApplication.java:152)
at MazeApplication.main(MazeApplication.java:33)
```

Can't the array be initialized that way? If not why?

Comment: It's not your array stuff that's the issue, if my quick glance was correct. It's the fact that rand may be null.

Comment: I have it initialized like this static Random rand;

Comment: `Random rand` is variable declaration, it's not initialization. That's the root cause of your issue. And for future times, just debug through your code and you will get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide the whole code sample, but it looks like `rand` is probably null.

You can either do this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

Or, at the top of your input function:

```
private static int[][] input() {
    if(rand == null) // initialize Random for the first time
        rand = new Random();

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`at MazeApplication.input(MazeApplication.java:152)`
At this point the only possible null pointer is `rand`.

You should initialize your rand like this `Random rand = new Random();` at the beginning of `input()`;

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be a problem with the array, where do you initialise rand? 
You should do something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

before the for loop